General formula for $n$-th derivative for $x^{1-n}$
I am working on a problem involving the function $f(x)= x^{(1-n)}$.
I calculated few derivatives of it with Mathematica:
\begin{align}
\frac{d^{l}}{dx^{l}} f(x) &= \ldots l=1: (1-n)x^{-n} \\
&= \ldots l=2: (n^{2}-n) x^{-n-1} \\
&= \ldots l=3: -(n^{3}-n) x^{-n-2} \\
&= \ldots l=4: n(n+2)(n^{2}-1) x^{-n-3} \\
&= \ldots l=5: (-n-3)n(n-2)(n^{2}-1)x^{-n-4} 
\end{align}
but I cannot find a general rule from this. It should be something like
$\frac{d^{l}}{dx^{l}} f(x) = ... x^{-n-(l-1)}$
Any suggestions for the general rule? Thanks a lot.

The factors are $-(n-1)$, $(n-1)n$, $-(n-1)n(n+1)$, $(n-1)n(n+1)(n+2), \dots$ . Can you see the pattern now?
